# Minimum Date parameter for DatePicker does not function

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

Having a problem with DatePicker minDate; it simply does not register! I have tried to remove dateFormat, timeIntervals, showTimeSelectOnly with no luck, the user can still use past date for 'End time'. I also tried passing minDate as object ( minDate={new Date(2025, 1, 1) ) with no luck.

DatePicker parameters:

```
<div>
    Start Date & Time<br />
    <DatePicker
        minDate={new Date()}
        placeholderText='Start time'
        showTimeSelect
        selected={inDate}
        timeIntervals={15}
        filterTime={filterPassedTime}
        dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"
        onChange={handleInDate}
    />
</div>
<div>
    End time<br />
    <DatePicker
        minDate={inDate}
        placeholderText='End time'
        showTimeSelect
        showTimeSelectOnly
        selected={outDate}
        timeIntervals={15}
        filterTime={filterPassedTime}
        dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"
        onChange={handleOutDate}
    />
</div>
```

handleInDate and handleOutDate code:

```
const [inDate, setInDate] = useState(null);
const [outDate, setOutDate] = useState(null);   

const handleInDate = (date) => {
    setInDate(date);
};

const handleOutDate = (date) => {
    setOutDate(date);
};
```

Comment: You mean Material-UI DatePicker?

Comment: This:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker